# How to get two successive rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not quite sure if i put the best title, but what i am looking for is:

i have the following table :

```
action_time          action_data
2017-06-02 05:25:44      BB
2017-06-02 05:25:44      R
2017-06-02 05:27:02      A
2017-06-06 08:45:34      C
2017-06-06 08:45:38      BB
2017-06-06 08:45:41      R
2017-06-06 08:45:45      D
2017-06-18 13:12:37      F
2017-06-18 13:12:42      BB
2017-06-18 13:12:51      R
```

i am looking for a query that return rows where `BB` and `R` are in successive rows so my desirable output would be like following:

```
 action_time          action_data
2017-06-02 05:25:44      BB
2017-06-02 05:25:44      R
2017-06-06 08:45:38      BB
2017-06-06 08:45:41      R
2017-06-18 13:12:42      BB
2017-06-18 13:12:51      R
```

Comment: what do you mean by `successive rows`?

Comment: OP wants to filter results based on action_data. So it would go BB, then the next R record then the next BB record and so forth.

Comment: are there only these columns in the table? no numeric key to help us?

Comment: @ Kaddath there is also numeric action_id for every row

Comment: @Hatik i mean they come together , in row i and i+1

Comment: @sanaz Is it possible that by `successive rows` you mean being in pairs?

Comment: @ Hatik yes, exactly that's what i mean

Comment: forget what i said, if there can be elements removed, that would create holes in the ids. How i would do is to create a subquery with a created field that represent the index of the element (without holes). Then select the BB and R that have the abs of their index difference at 1. Maybe there is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that the time stamps are *not* exactly identical (as shown in the sample data).  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is provided by column values -- and if the ordering column is the same, then you might get unexpected results.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.action_data
              from t t2
              where t2.action_time < t.action_time
              order by t2.action_time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_action_data,
             (select t2.action_data
              from t t2
              where t2.action_time > t.action_time
              order by t2.action_time asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_action_data
      from t
     ) t
where ('BB', 'R') in ( (prev_action_data, action_data),
                       (action_data, next_action_data)
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select action_time, action_data
FROM table
WHERE action_data in ('BB', 'R')
Order by action_time, action_data asc
```

This will return only the `BB` and `R` data rows ordering them by time (which will put them together then ordering by data alphabetically (BB is before R)

Comment: Are you sure it will return only BB and R s that are in  immediate successive rows

Comment: @sanaz it will return only `BB` and `R` ordered by time, and according to your data in example it will indeed return your expected result. the only problem is that if there will be 2 or more `BB`'s it will not pair them

Comment: @sanaz did you try it? the where clause will restrict the returned rows to only be BB and R. Looking at your data both the BB's and R's have the same timestamp (for their pairing) so when the order by is executed it will first put them all in time order (effectively pairing up the rows with the same timestamp) then the order by sorts the timestamped groups alphabetically.

Comment: as @hatik says this is not garanteed if you have two sets with the exact same timestamp. however with recording to the millisecond it is unlikely. if you show the full table structure there maybe another column i can order by to ensure that it works 100% of the time